# Lagrange Cardinal Function Proof

Tags: numerical-methods

How can I use the Lagrange interpolation polynomial
$$p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n ℓ_i(x)f(x_i)$$
that interpolates $f(x)$ at distinct points: $x_0
, x_1, ..., x_n$ where $ℓ_i(x)$’s are cardinal functions to show that
$$\sum^n_{i=0}ℓ_i(x) = 1$$, for all x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the interpolation polynomial on $f(x)=1$